# Libgdx camera not working

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I am creating a game where a player is moving upwards constantly and i want the camera to follow this player, i have tried this by using this code:         sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

```
    cam.position.x = p.getPosition().x;

    cam.position.y = p.getPosition().y;

    cam.update();
```

But it does not work. Here is the initizalizaion of the camera aswell:

```
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); 

    cam.setToOrtho(false); 

    cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0); 

    cam.update();
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful about the order of the code

Call

```
cam.position.x = p.getPosition().x;
cam.position.y = p.getPosition().y;
cam.update();
```

Before

```
sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

Hope this works for you!